# side-by-side inputlisting in landscape over multiple pages

Tags: listings, landscape

I'm pretty new to (la)tex, and working on a document right now in which I wanted to have two inputlistings side-by-side in landscape mode.
The problem now is that with this code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{code}{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\ttfamily, 
    frame=single,
    tabsize=2,
    breaklines=true,
    belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
    showstringspaces=false,
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{minipage}{.48\textheight}
            \lstinputlisting[escapeinside={(*}{*)},style=code,captionpos=b,caption=file1]{file1.cpp}
        \end{minipage}\hspace{20pt}
        \begin{minipage}{.48\textheight}
            \lstinputlisting[escapeinside={(*}{*)},style=code,captionpos=b,caption=file2]{file2.cpp}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

I get a blank page before the listings, and my code starts on the second and gets cut off, if it's longer than the page.
I addition to that, is it possible to display the caption on every page?

I already searched for possible solutions, but I haven't found any for this explicit usecase, most of them were explaining how to do it with tables.

Some useful insight to this is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe you want to have a look at `tcolorbox`. With its `\tcbinputlisting` you can customize how the caption should be shown after pagebreaks and with `tcbraster` you could get them side-by-side.

Comment: I know of [`paracol`](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol) but there are also [other packages](https://ctan.org/topic/parallel) for typesetting parallel columns.