# Landscape view, two separate columns with listings over multiple pages

Tags: minipage, code, landscape, lstlisting

I want to compare two codes in two different languages in latex. I use `lstlisting` for both of them and then I want to see them side by side. I archived this using `minipage` environment but my listings are bigger than one page so they are overlapped. Also I have a strange empty page before listings. `Multicols`environment doesn't allow me to see listings side by side.
Anybody know solution?

I use code like this

```latex
\begin{landscape}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\columnwidth}
  \begin{lstlisting}[caption=code 1,frame=tlrb]{Name}
    void code()
    {
    }
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\columnwidth}
  \begin{lstlisting}[caption=code 2,frame=tlrb]{Name}
    void code()
    {
    }
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{landscape}
```

This is how it looks if i use `paracol`
[image: Result using paracol]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Maybe you can make use of the `paracol` package as already suggested in the comments on this related question: side-by-side inputlisting in landscape over multiple pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/377797/134144)[

Comment: Hi, i uploaded image how it looks if i use `paracol` package

Comment: Unfortunately my ides using `paracol` only seems to work in portrait pages. Would that be an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that paracol is incompatible with pdflscape and IIRC listings can't break pages.  You can use paracol to create a side by side two page layout, but it leaves the remainder of the right page blank.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\globalcounter{lstlisting}% if you want different caption numbers

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}[1]{2}
  \begin{lstlisting}[caption=code 1,frame=tlrb]{Name}
    void code()
    {
    }
  \end{lstlisting}
\switchcolumn
  \begin{lstlisting}[caption=code 2,frame=tlrb]{Name}
    void code()
    {
    }
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{paracol}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

It is also possible to store lstlisting in a savebox and use adjustbox to crop it into page sized chunks.  See [cropping boxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204703/multicols-not-breaking-procedures-in-algorithm2e/204792?r=SearchResults&s=5%7C21.9860#204792) and [boxing lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414028/how-to-use-verbatim-with-tcolorbox/414034?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C14.6840#414034).